# Div positions for responsive page bootstrap 3

Tags: responsive-design

I am trying to convert a page to responsive using bootstrap 3. need 3 divs

[image]

in mobile version need DIV2 to display below div3.

Is it possible to do as with current code it displays

DIV1

---

DIV2

---

DIV3

Sample page : http://www.examguides.com/Networkplus/network-plus-1.htm

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before continuing, could you please spend a minute and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/bmbZaG

**HTML**

```
<div class="row parent">
  <div class="col-md-8 div1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-12  div3">Div 3</div>
  <div class="col-md-4  div2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row.parent{
  position:relative;
}

/* move .div2 to top right of .row.parent when viewport is 992px or more */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .div2{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is exactly what i was trying. Thanks.